# Drupal - using views_embed_view with an external Drupal site

Tags: drupal, external, drupal-views

I have two Drupal sites hosted on different servers. In the main they need to operate separately however site1 has one specific content type which I'd like to show in a list on site2.

I can't simply use feeds to import as the original has to remain and if edited, the changes be instantly reflected on both sites. Site2 has no requirement to edit the content - only show it.

The content is already being presented in a list on site1. The list was created using views.

My intention was to call the view on site2 using the following code in a custom module.

```
function site2_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['content-from-site1'] = array(
    'title' => 'Content from Site1',
    'page callback' => 'site_two_list',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}

function site2_list() {
  db_set_active('site1');
  $content = views_embed_view('articles', 'default');
  db_set_active('default');  
  return $content;
}
```

site1 DB is defined in the settings.php file.

However this isn't returning any data. Using the same approach on Site1 (without switching DBs) works fine.

Was I being over-optimistic in hoping this approach would work or am I missing something obvious?

If this isn't likely to work, what would the alternative be? I can do my own SQL query, but I'd prefer to use views for built in arguments, pagination, templates, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to use iframe to display site1 information in site2.

Comment: @viswanath-polaki - there's no need to use an iFrame to display information from one Drupal site in another. Drupal supports on-the-fly changes of DB. It's simply a case of getting the syntax correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to use views_embed_view, however I have been able to use views_get_view to retrieve everything I need and iterate over the results myself. It's a very close second.

```
function site2_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['content-from-site1'] = array(
    'title' => 'Content from Site1',
    'page callback' => 'theme_site2_list',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}

function site2_theme() {
  return array (
    'site2_list_page' => array(
      'arguments' => array('content' => NULL),
      'template' => 'templates/site2-list-page'
    )
  );
}

function theme_site2_list() {
  db_set_active('site1');
  $view = views_get_view('articles');
  $view->base_database = "site1";
  $view->init_display();
  $view->pre_execute();
  $view->execute();
  db_set_active('default');  
  foreach ($view->result as $key => $data) {
    $content[$key]['nid'] => $data->nid;
    $content[$key]['title'] => $data->node_title;
    $content[$key]['body'] => $data->field_body;   
    $content[$key]['image'] => $data->field_field_image;             
  }
  return theme('site2_list_page', array('content' => $content));  
}
```

Then in site2-list-page.tpl.php I can use the $content array to do what I need. It's not quite as clean as a simple views_embed_view, but it's a close second and allows the content from one site to be pulled to another fairly easily.